# Recover data from fusion drive on late 2015 17 inch iMac which no longer displays (possibly burnt)

Tags: imac, fusion-drive, file-recovery

This time last Christmas my fusion hard drive stopped working. It had been loud and the back of the iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, Late 2015) was burned. After eventually installing the macOS onto the 121.3 GB hard drive. I see plenty of threads stating to reset my hard drives back into one, but I have tried that unsuccesfuly and also I wish to get my files back. I understand the mechanical failure however I would like to try everything before giving up on this.

I have see videos on how to get the hd out of the iMac and connect this to another computer, also using another iMac and thunderbolt cable to locate the files, all the way to software apps that can do deep dives. My question is, if the mac can't see the fusion drive anymore then nothing can and surely it's a mechanical failure and the only possible fix would be to take out the hard drive and hope its a pin or connection issue. I'd much prefer to do this in the sofware, however.

Please see below and ignore the Seagate external hard drive (which is also coincidentally 2Tb and caused me much initial confusion). I'm still missing the fusion hd. If it's a total lost cause I guess I'll just try and reset them or give up on my 2Tb of hard space.

Many thanks for any assistance.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please see [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged).

Answer (score 2):

***"After eventually installing macOS onto the 121.3 GB hard drive."***

A fusion drive is one virtual volume spread across two separate physical devices. In this case, a 120Gb SSD (for speed), and a 2TB mechanical drive (for size). A file may be on the SSD, the HDD, or shared across both. *(Not duplicated, split!)*

If either one of the two devices fails, or is removed, or erased -- the data is **gone**. You've got half the pieces of a jigsaw, and no picture on the box.

It sounds like you had some catastrophic hardware failure involving "burning". The Hard drive is now no longer available. This isn't a software problem: you (or someone) will need to open up the Mac and assess the condition. A 7-year-old mechanical drive is at the end of its expected life, anyway.

Whatever the state of the Fusion drive at the point of the failure, recreating the SSD as a separate volume and reinstalling the OS will also have destroyed the fusion.

**It is vitally important to have additional, separate copies of any files that you want to keep.**

Comment: I always think of a Fusion a little like a RAID 0. Lose any one member & you've lost the lot.